# Влияют ли частые медиа запросы на время загрузки сайта?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Собственно в вопросе все указано...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по WebKit и Gecko оба механизма выполняют сериализацию и отсеивают дублированные медиа-запросы, поэтому им нужно только один раз оценить каждый медиа-запрос. Также они кэшируют запросы, чтобы впоследствии они могли повторно использовать их.

Конечно, это не означает, что нет разницы, но, глядя на принципы работы (код можно посмотреть на гитхабе), не должно быть проблемы с производительностью. Кроме того, полагаю, что при оценке сотен различных медиа-запросов, которые можно распознавать, нет недостатка в вычислительной мощности.

Другой вопрос - **эстетика и расширяемость кода**. Даже, если проектом занимается только один разработчик, ему спустя 3+ месяцев такой код дорабатывать будет немного (мягко говоря) затратно. С большой вероятностью возникнут дубли одних и тех же селекторов с одинаковыми свойствами. Про порог вхождения стороннего разработчика молчу. Скорее всего, в процессе выполнения ТЗ он просто накидает туда еще костылей.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ) просто я хочу сетку свою создать, пытаюсь через миксины и медиа-запросы выкрутиться)

Comment: @bytesmite, из-за чего конкретно возникает такая необходимость?

Comment: хочу сделать адаптивную сетку на flexbox'ах. Пишу свойства к блокам на SCSS, а в конечном CSS'е выдавалось под каждый размер экрана. Надеюсь понятно xD

Comment: Bootstrap 4 поддерживает flex.

Comment: @labris, я это знаю, я просто не хочу классы писать. Я на SASS хочу писать свойства